# proxy pattern in Python

Tags: python, design-patterns

This is my try at [the proxy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern).

What do you Pythoneers think of my attempt?

```
class Image:
    def __init__( self, filename ):
        self._filename = filename
    def load_image_from_disk( self ):
        print("loading " + self._filename )
    def display_image( self ):
        print("display " + self._filename)

class Proxy:
    def __init__( self, subject ):
        self._subject = subject
        self._proxystate = None

class ProxyImage( Proxy ):
    def display_image( self ):
        if self._proxystate == None:
            self._subject.load_image_from_disk()
            self._proxystate = 1
        print("display " + self._subject._filename )

proxy_image1 = ProxyImage ( Image("HiRes_10Mb_Photo1") )
proxy_image2 = ProxyImage ( Image("HiRes_10Mb_Photo2") )


proxy_image1.display_image() # loading necessary
proxy_image1.display_image() # loading unnecessary
proxy_image2.display_image() # loading necessary
proxy_image2.display_image() # loading unnecessary
proxy_image1.display_image() # loading unnecessary
```

Output:

```
loading HiRes_10Mb_Photo1
display HiRes_10Mb_Photo1
display HiRes_10Mb_Photo1
loading HiRes_10Mb_Photo2
display HiRes_10Mb_Photo2
display HiRes_10Mb_Photo2
display HiRes_10Mb_Photo1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like overkill to implement a class to represent the proxy pattern. *Design patterns are patterns, not classes.* What do you gain from your implementation compared to a simple approach like the one shown below?

```
class Image(object):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self._filename = filename
        self._loaded = False

    def load(self):
        print("loading {}".format(self._filename))
        self._loaded = True

    def display(self):
        if not self._loaded:
            self.load()
        print("displaying {}".format(self._filename))
```

Some other notes on your code:

1. It doesn't follow [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). In particular, "Avoid extraneous whitespace [...] immediately inside parentheses."
2. No docstrings.
3. It makes more sense to use `True` and `False` for a binary condition than to use `None` and `1`.
4. It's not necessary to append the class name to all the methods. In a class called `Image`, the methods should just be called `load` and `display`, not `load_image` and `display_image`.
5. You should use new-style classes (inheriting from `object`) to make your code portable between Python 2 and 3.

Comment: I think it can make sense to have separate `Image` and `ImageProxy` objects (though a better name might be something like `LazyImage`), because of separation of concerns. And even better (assuming the added complexity would be worth it) would be some sort of generic `LazyLoadingProxy` class, which could work with `Image`s and also other objects.

Comment: It's possible, but we'd only know in the context of a whole application: if there really are several different types of assets that need to be lazily loaded, then it might make sense to have a class to handle the lazy loading, but it might still be simpler to implement that class as a mixin rather than a proxy. A proxy object is usually a last resort when you don't control the code for the class you are proxying.